# Write at Test Class for a really simple class

Tags: unit-test, email-template, class

I have this really simple class that is being used in a Visualforce Email template.

```
public class getFields {

public String selectedProjName{get;set;}

public List<Login_Web_Location__c> getLocations() {
    return [
    SELECT Web_Location_URL__c 
    FROM Web_Location__c 
    where Protected_Application__c 
    in(
    SELECT Protected_Application__c 
    FROM ProjectAppLink__c 
    where Project_Name__c=:selectedProjName)];
     }
}
```

My question is, how do I write a test class for it?
I don't know where to start please advise.

Comment: You can find [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) a tutorial explaining how to write a test class. For your class, you only have to insert a ProjectAppLink__c  object, then a Web_Location__c object with the Protected_Application__c field set to the same value of the ProjectAppLink__c object previously inserted. After that, you make an assert verifying that the getLocations method returns the right values.

Comment: Please find this tutorial for Getting Started with Apex Unit Tests    https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro?id=apex_testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apex testing:**

- Unit tests are class methods that verify whether a particular piece of code is working properly.
- Unit test methods take no arguments, commit no data to the database, send no emails, and are flagged with the testMethod keyword or the isTest annotation in the method definition.
- Also, test methods must be defined in test classes, that is, classes annotated with isTest.
- At least 75% of your Apex code must be covered by unit tests, and all of those tests must complete successfully.
- Calls to System.debug are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
- Test methods and test classes are not counted as part of Apex code coverage.
- The default access level in Apex is private. The testing framework can always find the test methods and execute them, regardless of their access level.
- Classes defined as isTest must be top-level classes and can't be interfaces or enums.
- Test methods can’t be used to test Web service callouts. Instead, use mock callouts
- Modify the code in your class to expose public methods that will make use of these private class members, or you can simply annotate these private class members with TestVisible.
- When you annotate private or protected members with this annotation, they can be accessed by test methods and only code running in test context.
- The IsTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation has no effect when added to Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 23.0 and earlier.
- **assert**(condition, msg)
  Asserts that the specified condition is true. If it is not, a fatal error is returned that causes code execution to halt.
- **assertEquals**(expected, actual, msg)
  Asserts that the first two arguments are the same. If they are not, a fatal error is returned that causes code execution to halt.
- **assertNotEquals**(expected, actual, msg)
  Asserts that the first two arguments are different. If they are the same, a fatal error is returned that causes code execution to halt.
- One should always write assert statements in test classes. Below is the link showing example of assert statements

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_example.htm

Just a short summary for you to begin.

Try below code

```
 @istest
 public class testClass{
     // isTest annotation is compulsory for for test classes.
    static testMethod void testMethod1(){
    // create these objects if you want to create test data. but in your case if you directly call the method ,you wil get 100% test coverage.
          ProjectAppLink__c  projectApp = new ProjectAppLink__c (Protected_Application__c ='any value according to field type',Project_Name__c='test');
          Web_Location__c webLocation = new Web_Location__c (Web_Location_URL__c ='any',Protected_Application__c ='any');

          // after creating test data call the method of main class
          getFields gf = new getFields ();
          // set variables according to your business logic in main class
          gf.selectedProjName='test';
         gf.getLocations();

         // It is also a good practice to write assert statement in test class. It depends on your business 
        logic and return type of method which assert statement you use. For the sake of simplicity I am giving a link having examples of assert statement


  }

}
```

Comment: Can you add an assignment to `selectedProjName` and an assertion and comment those too?

Comment: @KeithC is right here. All Unit Tests, whether 0%, 75% or 100% are bad without assertions.

Comment: Yeah i agree with @KeithC. I will edit my code soon. just added a short summary for apex testing

Comment: @max can you please add an assertion example for selectedProjName?

Comment: given a link to show how to use assert statements.